# не видит class laravel

Tags: laravel

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\PostsModel;
class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
            $posts = PostsModel::all();
            var_dump($posts);
            return view('layouts.main');
    }
}
```

Выдает

> Class 'App\Models\PostsModel' not found

хотя файл модели содержится в папке `models`.
Создавал модель через `artisan` после перенес в папку `models`

Answer (score 1):

Очень может быть, что вы не изменили `namespace` в классе модели. Он там так и остался `namespace App` а лежит в другом месте.

Comment: Будет здорово, если вы добавите правильный вариант пространства имен для модели исходя из вашего предположения. `namespace App\Models;`

Comment: Я не знаю, правильный ли мой мой вариант, т.к. я не вижу что написано в шапке класса модели, я лишь предположил, что если человек создавал класс artisan командой, а затем руками перенес в другое место, то он мог забыть изменить namespace класса. Он пишет `use App\Models\PostsModel;` а у этого класса `namespace`  другой, вот он и не находится.